# Unity object with character controller falls through ground even if collider is in the ground?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a third person shooter game and I have applied character controller and rigidbody to my character. But character falls through the ground. No matter what I do I cant stop that from happening. Neither it calls OnCollision Function. But collider is working on cube and other objects. Why it is happening?

From some research I have found that character controllers and rigidbody dont go well together. And yeah character is from mixamo. Please help me

Comment: Are you sure that your character's collider has IsTrigger box unchecked?

Comment: @kilj yup anyway character controller dont have any options like that.I am not a beginner in game development and properly know the difference between collision and trigger

Comment: I was gonna say that Unity's build in character controller and rigidbody does not go well together. I've also had similar problem. But in the end i kept the rigidbody and created my own script for character controller.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using mesh collider, check convex property is enable so it can collide with another one.